# scipy.sparse vstack or hstack when two matrices have different numbers of rows and columns

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I have multiple sparse matrices I want to merge into one.

Each matrice is made up of the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from local_utils import get_data


def _count_words_within_userid(x):
        model = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1, 2), binary=True)
        transformed_data = model.fit_transform(x)
        return transformed_data 


data = get_data()

user_models_and_data = data.groupby("user_id")["text"].apply(_count_words_within_userid)
```

`user_models_and_data` now consists of a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` where the number of rows in all of the matrices sums up to the total number of rows in `data`.

I want to create one matrix with shape `(data_train.shape[0],n_cols)` where `n_cols` is the sum of columns of all of the matrices i.e simply concat all the rows and all the columns of all of the matrices.

The issue is that they all have different number of rows and columns, thus I can't `vstack` nor `hstack` them.

What I'm looking for is some kind of "outer join" with zero-filled values e.g

```
m1 = [[0,0,1,
     [0,1,0]]

m2 = [[0,1],
      [1,1]
      [1,0]]

result = some_function((m1,m2))

# The first 3 columns are from m1, the next 2 columns are from m2.
# The rows from "m2" are concatted to the rows of m1
# and have 0's in all of m1  columns (the first 3).
# and the rows from m1 have 0's in all of the columns from m2 (the last 2)
# such that we get a shape of `(m1.rows+m2.rows, m1.columns+m2.columns)`


print(result)

#  [[0,0,1,0,0],
#   [0,1,0,0,0],
#   [0,0,0,0,1],
#   [0,0,0,1,1],
#   [0,0,0,1,0]
#   ]
```

Comment: look at `sparse.bmat`

Answer (score 0):

I did it by the following approach

1. Create the full result matrix
2. For each matrix in matrices; add its value to the full result, but with an offset

   - The offset is just the sum of previous matrices rows and columns

```py
    total_rows = sum([p.shape[0] for p in matrices])
    total_col = sum([p.shape[1] for p in matrices])

    result = lil_matrix((total_rows,total_col))
    offset_col = 0
    offset_row = 0
    for m in matrices:
        m_rows = m.shape[0]
        m_col = m.shape[1]
        row_index = m_rows + offset_row
        col_index = m_col + offset_col

        result[offset_row:row_index, offset_col:col_index] = m
        offset_col +=m_col
        offset_row += m_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for `sparse.hstack` you'll see that it uses `sparse.bmat`.  And looking at its docs we can see that we can use it as follows:

```
In [48]: from scipy import sparse

In [49]: m1 = [[0,0,1],[0,1,0]] 
    ...: m2 = [[0,1],[1,1], [1,0]]  
In [50]: M1 = sparse.coo_matrix(m1)
In [51]: M2 = sparse.coo_matrix(m2)
```

According to the docs, `None` can be used as place holder for zeros blocks:

```
In [54]: M = sparse.bmat([[M1,None],[None,M2]])

In [55]: M
Out[55]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [56]: M.A
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Under the covers, `bmat`, converts the inputs to `coo` format, and then combines their respective `data, row, col` attributes into a set of 3 arrays.  It then makes a new `coo` matrix from those.  The combination of `row` and `col` arrays is done with the necessary offsets.

Packaging your `lil` based approach as a function, I can compare the times:

```
In [66]: timeit foo([M1,M2])
698 µs ± 384 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [67]: timeit M = sparse.bmat([[M1,None],[None,M2]])
429 µs ± 564 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

`bmat` is a bit faster, but the `lil` approach isn't bad.

`bmat` also scales better, though the input is a bit more awkward (but could be streamlined):

```
In [68]: timeit foo([M1,M2,M1,M2])
1.35 ms ± 1.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [69]: timeit M = sparse.bmat([[M1,None,None,None],[None,M2,None,None],[None,None,M1,None],[None,None,None,M2]])
    ...: 
644 µs ± 1.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```